# How to Create a Incremental Array to Make a Bulk Insert?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, builder

I need to do something like the example below but I do not know how to add the field to the array.

```
    $column_count = 0;
    foreach ($line as $column) {

        $array_line[$column_count] = $field_names[$column_count] => $column;
        $column_count++;
    }
    DB::table('table')->insert($array_line);
```

When I tried to execute like this:

```
    $column_count = 0;
    foreach ($line as $column) {

        $array_line[$column_count] = [$field_names[$column_count] => $column;]
        $column_count++;
    }
    DB::table('table')->insert($array_line);
```

I get an error that shows me how Laravel set up my query and it looks like this:

```
    INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES (value_original_column_1), (value_original_column_2), (value_original_column_3);
```

When te correct way should be:

```
    INSERT INTO table (column1, colum2, column3) VALUES (value_original_column_1, value_original_column_2, value_original_column_3);
```

Comment: If you have array of records to be inserted then same insert function will work for you.

Comment: show ur $line array ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$column_count = 0;
$array_line =[];
$line = ['column1','column2'];
$field_names = [ 0 => "title",1=>"description"];
 foreach ($line as $column) {
   $array_line[$field_names[$column_count]] =   $column;
        $column_count++;
 }
\DB::table('post')->insert($array_line);
```

Comment: On the line 4 of your example you fill the $field_names like this:

        $field_names = [ 0 => "title",1=>"description"];

It sould work if I fill it like the exemple below?

        $field_names = [ 0 ] = "title"; 
        $field_names[1] = "description";

Comment: $field_names = [ 0 ] = "title"; This is a wrong syntax. If you want to add "title" in the first index of the array, then please create $field_names as an array $field_names =[];. After this assign title to the 0th index of array using $field_names[0]="title". Instead of adding one index to the array you can use line number 4 in my code which is doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to fill the column count:

```
DB::table('table')->insert(array_map(function ($item) {
    $item['column_count'] = count(array_keys($item));
    return $item;
}, $lines));
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please, show me how this Array $lines should be?